# What is charge actually?

Tags: electricity

It is said that charge is a property of fundamental matter but mass is also property of matter even we can realize the term mass i.e. it indicates how hard it is to drag a matter. What kind of property charge is and who gave the the concept of of charge and why it is called charge?

Comment: FWIW, in [Kaluza-Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza–Klein_theory), charge is momentum in a compact extra dimension of space.

Answer (score 0):

Particles can have more than one properties such as its *mass*, its *electric charge*, its *spin* and so on. If mass determines inertia, electric charge determines how it responds to an applied electric field (or magnetic field, if in motion) and spin determines how it responds to an external magnetic field. An obvious distinction between the mass of a particle and its electric charge is that the latter can be both positive and negative.

Comment: Spin only determines how a particle responds to a magnetic field if ithe particle is charged.

Comment: @G.Smith Any particle (composite or elementary) having a nonzero spin will interact with an external magnetic field irrespective of whether it is electrically charged or neutral. Right?

Comment: I don’t think so. It will only have a magnetic moment if it is charged. For example, a photon (spin-1) doesn’t get deflected when passing through an external magnetic field, but an electron does.

Comment: @G.Smith "_It will only have a magnetic moment if it is charged._" What about neutrinos? They can have nonzero magnetic moment without being charged. But your other point "_a photon (spin-1) doesn’t get deflected when passing through an external magnetic field_" is probably true and I'm wondering!

Comment: The magnetic moment of a neutrino is very tiny and only exists because a neutrino has weak interactions with charged W bosons.

Comment: @G.Smith True. But this mean that it's in principle not forbidden for a particle with zero charge to have a magnetic moment! Anything wrong in my answer? I just disagreed with "_It will only have a magnetic moment if it is charged._"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91739/discussion-between-srs-and-g-smith).

Comment: @G.Smith Neutrons have magnetic moments

Comment: @AaronStevens Neutrons have magnetic moments because of the charged quarks inside them.

Comment: @SRS My only objection to your answer is how you characterized spin. Knowing only a particle’s spin tells you nothing about how strongly it responds to an external magnetic field. You have to know its magnetic moment, and that depends on more than just its spin. It will have a zero magnetic moment unless the particle is charged, or contains charged constituents, or interacts with virtual charged particles.

Comment: @G.Smith So you should qualify your statement to say you aren't talking about composite particles I guess.

Comment: @AaronStevens I can’t edit old comments after five minutes. Our discussion, and my comment before this one, has clarified the situation.